# Hide virtual function with non-virtual override

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding, virtual-functions

Having

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "B" << endl;
    }
};

class C : public B {
public:
    void foo() {
        cout << "C" << endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    C c;
    B* b = &c;
    b->foo();

    return 0;
}
```

The output is `C`, but I expected `B`.

I didn't declare `B::foo()` with the `virtual` modifier, so I expect the function call to be determined by the static type (no polymorphism).

Why is `C::foo()` being called?

Is it possible to provide a non-virtual function in a derived class, that hides the virtual function in the base?  What signature should the derived member function have so that `b->foo()` calls it, and not `(b->*&A::foo)()`

Comment: `B::foo()` *is* virtual. The premise of your question is wrong.

Comment: The virtual is inherited from A. You do not need to re-specify it (although I recommend that you do for clarity).

Comment: thanks! do i delete the question?

Comment: @I've given your question a more accurate title.  It is a reasonable question and can be given a good answer.  Now that you know the issue, why don't you edit your question to match reality, so others can benefit from a good explanation?  (i.e. "I didn't declare `B::foo()` as virtual" instead of ``B::foo()` isn't virtual")

Comment: no I disagree with deleting this question. @juanchopanza several people dont know that. IMHO an answer with a small explanation is needed. Unless it is a duplicate.

Comment: As it stands, the question is one of these: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258731/close-reason-for-not-in-my-universe-questions

Comment: Instead of tagging on `virtual` to `B::foo`, I suggest instead to tag on `override`.

Comment: Actually, I made the edits I was thinking of for you.  I hope this preserves the essence of your question, while no longer assuming "facts" contrary to reality.

Comment: BTW: http://ideone.com/MNNKBi  A default argument would probably be better than `...`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20650875/103167

Answer (score 5):

The principle of virtual inheritance of a member function is is a direct consequence of the C++ Standard:

> 10.3/2:  If a virtual member function vf is declared in a class Base and in a class Derived, **derived directly or indirectly** from Base,
>   a member function vf with the same name, parameter-type-list ,
>   cv-qualification, and refqualifier (or absence of same) as Base::vf is
>   declared, then Derived::vf is **also virtual**.

So regardless of the level of inheritance, the function will be virtual in all the classes derived somehow from A.  There is no need to put the keyword `virtual`.

The goal of this polymorphic approach is to ensure that you always call the appropriate function corresponding to the real idendity of your object, regardless the fact that you use a pointer to a base or a pointer to the real class of the object.   This is why you obtain "C" !

In [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606941/how-to-override-a-virtual-function-with-a-non-virtual-function/28618981#28618981) I explain a trick to give the impression of removing virtuality at one single level, using multiple inheritance.  However it can be done only for a single level  (you should do it for the class of your base pointer).

*By the way, you could write `pb->B::foo();` no need of `*&`.